# How can I know if an DOM element is currently on screen using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Is there a function, or plugin, that tells me if more than 50% of a `<div>` block is currently being displayed?

I know there are things like `$.offset()` but I didn't want to do it by hand every time the user resizes it's window or scroll to a region.

Something on the lines of `:visible`, but that is currently visible.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of content is within the div?

Comment: The div contains only a `<p>` with plain text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your definition of "visible" is "more than 50% of the div on the screen", you're going to need to create a function of your own to calculate this.

You will need to define exactly what portion of the `<div>` you are calculating - i.e. margins, borders, elements hidden in `scrollTop`/`scrollLeft`, etc...

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat late to this party, but there is indeed a JQuery plug-in for this:

The [Is On Screen](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/isOnScreen) plug-in can be downloaded from here: http://plugins.jquery.com/node/16506/release and there is also [a demo page](http://spectrum.0sites.net/demos/isOnScreen/isOnScreen_Demo.html)

Hope that helps.